# Negative lookahead to not capture a space if last character is a space

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to capture the first 36 characters of a string, unless the last character is a space. I don't want the space. What have I done wrong here? Eventually, I'd like to have it check that it is not a space or a comma or a colon. Is this possible?

```
.{36}(?! )
```

Also, why has the first letter not been selected?

http://regex101.com/r/fP9tB8/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your request as

> Match the first 36 characters if the last character is not a space; match 35 otherwise.

That would be done with

```
^.{35}[^ ]
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qI9hY9/2)

If you want "no colon, comma or space" you need

```
^.{35}[^:, ]
```

If (per your most recent comment) you want "no space, comma or colon at the end - then the longest string less than 36 character long" you get

```
^.{1,35}[^,: ](?![^: ,])
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qI9hY9/4)

Explanation: this matches

```
^        starting at the beginning
.{1,35}  at most 35 of anything
[^,: ]   not followed by , : or space
(?![^:, ]) not followed by something that isn't , : or space (two negatives...)
```

Confirming:

```
poas apodka sapodkfas adksidfj odfda: asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf:  gi oaidfg
```

matched up to

```
poas apodka sapodkfas adksidfj odfda
```

but

```
poas apodka sapodkfas adksidfj odf da: asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf:  gi oaidfg
```

matches to

```
poas apodka sapodkfas adksidfj odf
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your regex as:

```
^.{1,36}(?<![ ,:])
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fP9tB8/3)

Your regex `.{36}(?! )` is trying to find **any 36 character string (not followed by a space)**.

Comment: `^.{1,36}(?! )` given `"poas apodka sapodkfas adksidfj odf   gi oaidfg"` will only match to the `d` in `odf`. But that is only 33 characters. Why does it not match the f as well? http://regex101.com/r/qR3rS1/1

Comment: What behavior do you want if there is no space on 37th character?

Comment: I want to match the first 36 characters of the string. Unless there are spaces, colons, or commas at the end. Then I just want longest string of characters possible that doesn't end in a space, comma, or colon.

Comment: @thomas: It's still unclear. What do you want to happen if there is no space after the 36th character? The idea may be perfectly clear to you, but as you can see, it is not for me, anubhava, and Floris. Could you please update the question with stricter phrasing, and explain clearly what you want?